# How can we append list of list , with another list of item ,inside list of every list

Tags: python, list

having two list like following

```
l1=[56,92]
l2=[ [['abc','cda'],['abc','dba']] , [['xyz','sdf'],['sdf','dfg'],['pdf','hfg']] ]
```

i want output like this: (adding end of every list of that sublist)

```
l2=[ [['abc','cda',56],['abc','dba',56]] , [['xyz','sdf',92],['sdf','dfg',92],['pdf','hfg',92]] ]
```

Comment: Did you forget to [include your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I'm sure it tells you when you ask a question.

Comment: I am new here and sorry for that , I will remember next time. @Jab

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
 for i, sub_l2 in enumerate(l2):
        for l in sub_l2:
            l.append(l1[i])
```

Comment: this is working , but for other code like this it is showing 'str' object has no attribute 'append'